# How to Update data to HTML , when an ajax request is being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page which lists multiple shops details.For every shop ajax call is being made to get the product details.

```
function init_product_data(shop_id) {

        var uri = parseUri(location.href);
        var qs_product = uri.queryKey;
        qs_product.device       = "desktop";
        qs_product.shop_id       = shop_id;
        qs_product.rows = 3;

        $.ajax({
         url: search_ajax_product_url_v3,
         type: "GET",
         data: (qs_product),
         dataType: "json",
         timeout: 5000,
         success: function(result){
            //  $('#official-product_detail').html('');

             $('.official-product_detail').html(buildMicroBrandProductHtml(result));


            },
            complete: function() {

            },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });

}
```

Call init_prod_data for each shop:

```
for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
        init_product_data(result[i].shop_id);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-shop-product pull-right">
          <div class="official-product_detail">
          </div>
</div>
```

Problem is that the product details of the last ajax call result are being updated for all shops. How can I update the product detail for each shop inplace when the result is recieved.
Eg:

```
   <div class="grid-shop-product pull-right">
              <div class="official-product_detail">
              <!-- Products of Shop1-->
              </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-shop-product pull-right">
              <div class="official-product_detail">
              <!-- Products of Shop2-->
              </div>
    </div>
     .
     .
     .
    <div class="grid-shop-product pull-right">
              <div class="official-product_detail">
              <!-- Products of ShopN-->
              </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you have assign same class name to all div.for separation you need to assign 'official-product_detail' differently. like official-product_detail1,official-product_detail2 etc.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay. That worked.

Comment: See my answer below if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to loop through each div and then update that current div only with ajax result data.You can try following code in which, I am traversing through each `.official-product_detail` and passing it as a parameter to the function which further calls ajax and render only the same control with result data.

```
$(".official-product_detail").each(function(){
    init_product_data(shop_id,$(this));
});

function init_product_data(shop_id,control) {
        var cn = control;   //YOU CAN FIND THE CONTROL IF ITS DEEP INSIDE
        var uri = parseUri(location.href);
        var qs_product = uri.queryKey;
        qs_product.device       = "desktop";
        qs_product.shop_id       = shop_id;
        qs_product.rows = 3;

        $.ajax({
         url: search_ajax_product_url_v3,
         type: "GET",
         data: (qs_product),
         dataType: "json",
         timeout: 5000,
         success: function(result){
            //  $('#official-product_detail').html('');

             cn.html(buildMicroBrandProductHtml(result));


            },
            complete: function() {

            },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });

}
```